# Is it possible to "learn" randomness?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

Suppose that you have a set of inputs X and outputs Y. Your job is to predict Y given X.

Now, if X and Y are generated independently from uniform distributions `U(0,1)`, is it possible to "learn" this mapping? More concretely, we always assume that `P(X,Y) = P(X) P(Y|X)`, but what happens if `P(Y|X) = P(Y)`? Does this mean that there's no "relation" between X and Y?

Comment: Watch this video by Avi Wigderson, Institute for Advanced Study, Princeton, titled *Finding Hay in Haystacks: The Power and Limits of Randomness* and decide.

Comment: You can "learn it" and fit your model to some given training set. Maybe it even has a low error rate, nice, but then you check your model on test error and poof, you realize your model is performing worse than random predictions :)

Comment: The probability factorization you mention is not an *assumption*, it is a definition. There is nothing particularly weird about the situation you describe: you are just doing feature selection and discovering that $X$ is not a useful feature. In this case, since you have no other features, you'd end up with a prediction for $Y$ which is something like the mean or median of your training values for $Y$, depending on your loss function. This is a perfectly reasonable prediction.

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad ah yes, the generalization vs. learning issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make things more concrete, let's say we're doing classification. We can show that under 0-1 loss (and with a uniform prior over the values of the response) the best classifier is the Bayes classifier
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \hspace{1cm} \textrm{ if } \mathbb P(Y = 1 \vert X = x) > 0.5 \\ 0 \hspace{1cm} \textrm{ o.w. } \end{cases}
$$

Supposing that $Y \perp X$ then our optimal classifier is
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \hspace{1cm} \textrm{ if } \mathbb P(Y = 1) > 0.5 \\ 0 \hspace{1cm} \textrm{ o.w. } \end{cases}
$$
which does not depend on $X$. This means that the best we can do with predicting $Y$ using $X$ is to not use $X$ at all.